# Facebook like button should not use canonical link

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm implementing the Facebook "Like" button on our site, using the Javascript SDK.

It's working brilliantly, but when a user posts a comment, that message links back to the canonical link in the <head> section.

that's severely unwanted behaviour. Why go through the trouble of manually providing a link to have it overridden?

Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 3):

No - that's a feature of the Like system.

That's how it knows that a "likes" to disparate-looking URLs are actually to the same resource.  It's done this way quite deliberately - and I agree with the implementation.

In short - this is acting as intended.  Either dump the canonical link, or implement this differently.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this should be the behaviour; partly because I can't think of a reason to specify a canonical link that you don't want to use?

I found this question because I had the opposite problem in that my canonical link seemed to be being ignored, so I presume they have fixed this feature in Facebook

For me the data-href attribute overrides the canonical meta tag

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="YOU_LINK_GOES_HERE" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="45" data-show-faces="false" data-font="lucida grande"></div>
```